# TS2339: scrollLeft does not exist on type of GlobalEventHandlers

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, this

```js
 const el: HTMLElement = document.querySelector('.tip');
 el.onmouseout = function() {
    this.scrollLeft += 10;
 };
```

The error message, *TS2339: scrollLeft does not exist on type of GlobalEventHandlers*. `this` just points `el`, why wrong?

Typescript: 3.7.0, 3.5.2

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
const el: HTMLElement | null = document.querySelector('.tip');
if (el) {
    el.onmouseout = () => { el.scrollLeft += 10;};
 }
```

The problem is that all functions in JS could be called whit changing context, like: `el.onmouseout.call(newContext, arg1, arg2, ...)`, or `el.onmouseout.apply(newContext, [arg1, arg2, ...])`. So what you do is you create function and then assign it to `el` property, so this function know nothing about it's context, that's why you have error. And when you change `this` to concrete constant, TS will know it's type, and can handle it

Comment: The context is very clear and the operation is correct. The error is only eslint thinks the context is the current class.